# Reading C# property into JQuery code

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, properties

I'm trying to read the value of a C# property from my code behind file into some JQuery script (see below).  The JQuery selector I've written accesses an ASP.Net GridView and then a CheckBox field within the gridview.  Whenever a checkbox is checked or un-checked the code is hit, but I need to access the C# property from the code behind to take the appropriate action based on the value of the property.

```
    $(".AspNet-GridView-Normal > td > input").click(function() {

        //Need to access the C# property here

        //Take action here based on the value of the C# property

     });
```

Comment: I did this in Rails. Rails allows you to send javascript responses to AJAX requests - which is then executed clientside once it is received. However the code which generates this javascript could have arbitrary embedded ruby statements (e.g. like accessing an attribute to determine output). You could search if ASP.Net supports something like that. The C# Property exists only on the server side so this logic has to be done via server side processing.

Comment: Will you need to modify the value as check boxes are clicked?  So if you start off with AvailableInstalls set to 10, will you need to increment/decrement the variable as check boxes are clicked?

Comment: Yes, the variable will need to be decremented each time a checkbox is checked, and incremented each time a checkbox is un-checked.

Comment: Well in that case the solution presented by crescent fresh and updated by Ben Duguid is probably the most straight forward approach. You could combine that with my approach if you have a need to get the current value of the AvailableInstalls variable on page postback.  So essentially continually update the value of the hidden field so that value will be available on postback.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This may be stating the obvious, but the code behind doesn't exist on the client side where your jQuery code is executing.  What you could do is assign the value of the property to a hidden field on the server side so that when you need to check it with jQuery on the client side it will be available.  So you might do the following on the client side.

Markup:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfValueINeedToKnow" runat="server"/>
```

Code Behind:

```
hfValueINeedToKnow.Value = <some value>;
```

jQuery:

```
$("#<%= hfValueINeedToKnow.ClientID %>").val();
```

You might need to make some minor changes to support a value for each row of the grid, but hopefully this explains the general idea.

Comment: I'm having problems reading the value of the HiddenField, here is the JQuery code I'm using to access it:
            var availableInstalls = 
            $("#<%= hfAvailableInstalls.ClientID %>").val();
and I'm setting the value of the hidden field to "2" in the PageLoad method in the code behind, but I always get a value of "undefined" for the var AvailableInstalls when I walk through in debug mode.  Any ideas what may be causing this?

Comment: @Russ Clark - what is appearing in your HTML for the hidden input field, and the actual rendered value in the jQuery selector?

Comment: To the point, really helpful. Thank you. Been looking for this break down of actions for a while.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned in a comment that the value is an int. And I see it's also a `public` property in your codebehind. This is trivial now - you don't need to escape the value, nor access it in some round-about way, and you get type safety for free:

```
<script>
$(".AspNet-GridView-Normal > td > input").click(function() {

    var AvailableInstalls = <%= AvailableInstalls %>;

});
</script>
```

Comment: Based on the later comment from OP "the variable will need to be decremented each time a checkbox is checked, and incremented each time a checkbox is un-checked" declare the JS variable outside of the function, but this should work nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can't.

You need to render the C# property in some element (perhaps a hidden field) and then look at it that way.

But explain further: What property are you trying to check?

Comment: The property is just an int in the code behind, like this:

    public int AvailableInstalls { get; set; }

Comment: Right, well do it the hidden field way. Mark Kanof has given you the exact code to do it.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done for this scenario in the past is to print out my code value into the markup and store whatever it is in a javascript variable, thus making a copy of it available to client-side code. This is a silly example, but hopefully it makes sense:

```
<%
    var messsge = "Hello World!"
%>

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowMessage()
    {
        var msg = '<%= message %>';
        if(msg)
            alert(msg);
    }
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a really clean way to do this. Your best bet would probably be to use the `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` functionality built into ASP.NET. [Here's a good primer](http://www.aspcode.net/SystemWebUIPageRegisterClientScriptBlockstring-string-is-obsolete.aspx).

```
private int myValue;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), 
        "vars", "<script>var myParams = { p1: " + myValue + ", p2: 'My Name' };</script>");
}
```

This will put the supplied script on your page towards the top of the form. You can change that too. Obviously, it isn't the prettiest; you are essentially string concatenating a different language, but it will work, and for simple variable declaration isn't too rough on the eyes.

Answer (score 0):

ASP Embedded in JavaScript always makes me nervous from the perspective of script injection attacks and the inability to unit-test your JavaScript.

This build upon an ealier answer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".AspNet-GridView-Normal > td > input").click(function() {

    var AvailableInstalls = $("#MyHidden").val();

});
</script>
```

You could move it to a hidden variable:

```
<input type="hidden" id="#MyHidden" value="<%= AvailableInstalls %>" />
```

However this doesn't get around the problem of injection. So you could you could add a server-side hidden variable and set it from the Page_Load event function in ASP.NET.

(P.s. you also need the attribute type="text/javascript" in your script tag to make it valid HTML).

Answer (score 0):

If you will put your value into an asp:HiddenField with id hfValueINeedToKnow, the simplest way to retrieve this value client side is

```
var jsvar = $("[id$=hfValueINeedToKnow]").val();
```

So you can also place this code in a separate .js file.