# How to get parameters from aspx.cs to javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I get a data from database in aspx.cs like:

```
string abc = sdr["aaa"].ToString()
```

How can I call "string abc" in javascript part

thanks for answers

Comment: follow here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921633/using-c-sharp-variable-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

Simply render out your C# variable to the page so you can access it via JavaScript.

In .aspx.cs:

```
protected string abc {get;set;}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var sdr = GetData();
  abc = sdr["aaa"].ToString();
}
```

In .aspx:

```
<script>
var abc = '<%=abc%>';
alert(abc);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "temp", "<script language='javascript'>alert(" + abc + ");</script>", false)
```

Comment: If you specify last parameter as `true` you don't need to wrap your script with `<script...`